# Ability to do run test suite in single npm script to generate both testrail and mochawesome reports

Tags: cypress, testrail, mochawesome

Currently I have two separate scripts:

"p1_testRail": "cypress run -r cypress-testrail-accumulative-reporter {arguments} {test_suites} --headless"

"p1_mochawesome": "cypress run -r cypress-multi-reporters {arguments} {test_suites} --reporter mochawesome"

But I want to be able to run a single cypress script and get the report generated for both testrail and mochawesome. Do we have any way to be able to pass multiple arguments for a --reporter & -r?

NOTE: && would still run it one after another. That means, test suite will run twice. Instead, I want to run test suite once and update both the reporters at the same time.

Comment: See [cypress-multi-reporters - Configuring reporters](https://github.com/you54f/cypress-multi-reporters#configuring-reporters) in reporterEnabled try replacing `@my-org/custom` with `cypress-testrail-accumulative-reporter`. No idea if the testrail adapter is compatible, but easy to check out.

Comment: @HiramK.Hackenbacker, thanks for suggestion. I did already include as following but it doesn't make difference while using it in one single report-  "reporter": `"cypress-testrail-accumulative-reporter, cypress-multi-reporters",
  "reporterEnabled": "cypress-testrail-accumulative-reporter, mochawesome"`

Comment: Unfortunately, adding "cypress-testrail-accumulative-reporter, cypress-multi-reporters" this did not help it